# pip install from SVN [error 2]

Tags: python, svn, pip

Im trying to install my package via pip from a SVN repository.
Version of subversion server is 1.6.11.

I'm using the command below:

```
pip install -e svn+http://svn.mysite.com/svn/project/project#egg=project


Error [Error 2] Can not find the file while executing command svn checkout -q http://svn.mysite.com/svn/project/project/
Can not find command 'svn'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does this have to do with Django?

Comment: Right, my mistake. I'm just using it in Django environment.

Comment: FYI: SVN 1.6 is very old, outdated and no longer supported. Upgrade to SVN 1.9 or at least 1.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you don't have subversion installed or is misconfigured.

You can try `svn --version` in the terminal to check if you have subversion installed.

If you don't have it installed you can [install Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) via apt, brew or whatever package manager you use and try again.

Comment: Locally or on the server side?

Comment: Depends where you are executing the code, I guess locally.

Comment: You were right. I didin't have a subversion at local.